# Slerp issues, perspective warping

Tags: c++, quaternions, linear-interpolation

I'm essentially working on a function for [slerping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slerp) and while it kinda works, it's having a weird perspective warping issue that I'm stuck trying to work out right now.

```
Quaternion sLerp(Quaternion start, Quaternion end, float s)
{
    float dot = qDot(start, end);
    float theta = std::acos(dot);
    float sTheta = std::sin(theta);

    float w1 = sin((1.0f-s)*theta) / sTheta;
    float w2 = sin(s*theta) / sTheta;

    Quaternion Temp(0,0,0,0);

    Temp = start*w1 + end*w2;

    return Temp;
}
```

Essentially what it's doing (or should be doing) is just slerping between two values to provide a rotation, and the result from this is being converted to a rotation matrix. But what's going wrong is a horribly, horribly stretched view... for some reason during the rotation it stretched everything, starting with everything too long / thin and reaching a midpoint of being much shorter before starting to go back to being thin. Any help would be great.

Comment: Graphics would help. And isn't this just a maths question at heart?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your slerp code seems fine, although one would normally make sure that `dot>=0` because otherwise, you're rotating the long way around the circle.  In general, it's also important to make sure that `dot!=1` because you'll run into *divide-by-zero* problems.

A proper quaternion should never stretch the view.  Either you're passing in non-unit-length quaternions for `start` or `end`, or your quaternion-to-matrix code is suspect (or you're getting funky behavior because the angle between the two quaternions is very small and you're dividing by almost zero).

---

My code for converting from quaternion to a matrix for use in OpenGL:

```
// First row
glMat[ 0] = 1.0f - 2.0f * ( q[1] * q[1] + q[2] * q[2] );
glMat[ 1] = 2.0f * (q[0] * q[1] + q[2] * q[3]);
glMat[ 2] = 2.0f * (q[0] * q[2] - q[1] * q[3]);
glMat[ 3] = 0.0f;

// Second row
glMat[ 4] = 2.0f * ( q[0] * q[1] - q[2] * q[3] );
glMat[ 5] = 1.0f - 2.0f * ( q[0] * q[0] + q[2] * q[2] );
glMat[ 6] = 2.0f * (q[2] * q[1] + q[0] * q[3] );
glMat[ 7] = 0.0f;

// Third row
glMat[ 8] = 2.0f * ( q[0] * q[2] + q[1] * q[3] );
glMat[ 9] = 2.0f * ( q[1] * q[2] - q[0] * q[3] );
glMat[10] = 1.0f - 2.0f * ( q[0] * q[0] + q[1] * q[1] );
glMat[11] = 0.0f;

// Fourth row
glMat[12] = 0.0;
glMat[13] = 0.0;
glMat[14] = 0.0;
glMat[15] = 1.0f;
```

Comment: Hey, well the quaternions being passed in are 

start(0.92388f,0.f,-0.38268f,0.f);
end(0.85862f,0.11304f,0.49572f,-0.06526f);

and the code for transforming is 

Matrix4x4(1-4*Y - 4*Z,       2*(X*Y)-2*(W*Z),     2*(X*Z) + 2*(W*Y), 0,
          2*(X*Y)+2*(W*Z),   1-4*X - 4*Z,         2*(Y*Z) - 2*(W*X), 0,
          2*(X*Z) - 2*(W*Y), 2*(Y*Z) + 2*(W*X),   1-4*X-4*Y,         0,
          0,0,0,1);

sorry if its horribly spaced... but the quaternions were given as those and the matrix part was taken from a book / the web as they agreed with each other as that being how.

Comment: @user1930625 That's not quite the right transforming code.  You've mistaken "squaring" for "multiply by two".  The [0,0] element should be: `1.0f - 2.0f * ( Y*Y + Z*Z )`

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to normalise the quaternion?

I think the following:

```
float sTheta = std::sin(theta);
```

should be:

```
float sTheta = sqrt(1.0f - sqr(theta));
```

Comment: Hey, that shouldnt be the issue but we tried it anyways, wasnt the solution lol though it was pretty funny to see the result.. but yeh.. im really not sure what the issue is as its still even when using that stretching everything.